# Which is the best way to get taskboard items & columns?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

I'm trying to get taskboard items from the azure devops by using its API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/taskboard%20work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). Well, this thing works fine until I don't send the request to the newly created project/taskboard. The new one is marked as not customized and has some default bunch of column.

> GET
> [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/taskboardworkitems/{iterationId}?api-version=6.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/%7Bteam%7D/_apis/work/taskboardworkitems/%7BiterationId%7D?api-version=6.1-preview.1)

So in case of default columns the above endpoint returns me this:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Taskboard columns are not added. Customize the taskboard columns before accessing it.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Agile.Server.TaskBoard.TaskboardColumnNotCustomizedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Agile.Server",
    "typeKey": "TaskboardColumnNotCustomizedException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

However in the web app it works well even with not custmized columns. So is there any known workaround or something like that to handle this issue, or it's an API bug?

And I get similar issue with taskboard columns API.

> GET
> [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/taskboardcolumns?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/%7Bteam%7D/_apis/work/taskboardcolumns?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

This endpoint returns just an empty array of columns, although the web app shows the default list of columns depending on the process type of the project.

```
{
    "columns": [],
    "isCustomized": false,
    "isValid": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in the API (preview). Can you try a Workaround: goto Column Options in the taskboard, add all states of your tasks (for me it was "Removed" state, which was missing) and nevermind the "mapping state", execute the GET Api request again. now you should see the "normal" response. Go ahead and remove the additional added States Columns (revert Column Options to previous state) and try again the Api call. Now it should work (at least for me it did).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is that I'm trying to build an app around the Azure DevOps API. So users of the app won't see any taskboard item until they do some interactions with the existing web app. And in fact the endpoint will work fine if you just simply change the name of some column, save, revert the change and save again. So seems like it works only with the columns which have "isCustomized": true.

Comment: Hi @IvanHredil, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: In addition, This rest API is recently added. it just has preview version, the document should be updated in the future, we could follow the doc to get latest news.